# Merging dataframes in Pandas throws 'AssertionError: cannot create BlockManager._ref_locs'

Tags: python, merge, pandas

I'm trying to import several files from `csv` into a single `DataFrame` and am getting the following error when trying to add the third `DataFrame`.

```
AssertionError: cannot create BlockManager._ref_locs because block [ObjectBlock: [CompletionDate, Categories, DateEntered_x, <lots more columns here>...], dtype=object)] does not have _ref_locs set
```

The code is:

```
project = pandas.read_csv(read_csv('dbo_Project.csv')
project = pandas.read_csv(read_csv('dbo_ProjectEnergy.csv')
project = pandas.read_csv(read_csv('dbo_BuildingDescription.csv')
part_merged = pandas.merge(project, project_energy,
    on='ProjectID',
    how='outer')
part_merged = pandas.merge(part_merged, project_energy_data,
    on='ProjectEnergyID',
    how='outer')
part_merged = pandas.merge(part_merged, building_description,
    on='ProjectEnergyID',
    how='outer')
```

How should I be joining these `DataFrames` to avoid this problem?

**Edited in response to answer from Stefan Jansen:**

The new code up to the point where the new error occurs is:

```
project = pandas.read_csv(read_csv('dbo_Project.csv')
project = pandas.read_csv(read_csv('dbo_ProjectEnergy.csv')
part_merged = pandas.concat([project, project_energy],
    axis=1,
    join='outer')
part_merged.set_index(['ProjectEnergyID'])
part_merged = pandas.concat([self.part_merged,
    project_energy_data],
    axis=1,
    join='outer')
```

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: Just updated to 0.12 which is why I at least have a semi-intelligible error message now.

Comment: this bug is resolved in master, but concat is the right way to do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nice simple answer.

The issue was duplicated columns. The columns that caused the issue were not important and so I just dropped them before merging.

```
def remove_clashes(df):
    unwanted_cols = ['DataCompleteness', 'DeletedFlag','DateEntered', 'EnteredBy',
        'LastModified', 'MandatoryDataInput', 'ModifiedBy']
    return df.drop([col for col in unwanted_cols if col in df.columns], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using `pandas.concat()` for multiple frames. Also has `'outer'` option - [see documentation.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html)

This would work well in case the columns you want to merge on are index columns, which you can achieve using `pandas.set_index()`, possibly preceded by `.reset_index()`.

Comment: I'll give that a try. What's the equivalent of `on` to select the column to combine on?

Comment: Documentation says:`pandas.tools.merge.concat(objs, axis=0, join='outer', join_axes=None, ignore_index=False, keys=None, levels=None, names=None, verify_integrity=False)`. The idea is to use row or column index (`axis = 0 or 1`). Your 'ProjectEnergyID' sound like they could reasonably be set to index by `set_index(['ProjectEnergyID'])` after loading and then concatenating all DataFrames on this index.

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't seem to be working. What I end up with is a stack of the three dataframes with blanks for all columns which aren't present in the other dataframe. What I'm looking for is for those blanks to be filled in from the other dataframe where there is a match in the column I'm merging on.

Comment: The `axis=1` option allows you to concat horizontally using a common index for all DataFrames you want to merge. The default `axis = 0` will lead to a vertical stack.

Comment: Thanks, we're getting somewhere now I think. At least, it's working for the first concatenation - but then on the second one I get `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (136, 5), indices imply (136, 3)`

Comment: One of the dataframe arrives at `concat()` with two unexpected columns. You can print `DataFrame.columns` to see what the columns look like to pandas. Happy to provide a more constructive answer, but need more detail on code and table content.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35235/discussion-between-jamie-bull-and-stefan-jansen)